# 霹雳与雷霆有什么分别？(What's the difference between 霹雳 and 雷霆?)

Tags: word-choice, difference, synonyms

except for their other uses, such as 霹雳舞(breakdance) and their respective 成语, are they considered synonyms? they're both translated as

霹雳: thunderbolt

雷霆: thunderbolt

> 空中**雷霆**一响，就把孩子吓哭了 = The **thunderbolt** came from the sky, and frightened
> the child into crying.

> 我听到了一声**霹雳**，随后天空突然开始下起了雨 = I heard a **clap of thunder**, and then it
> suddenly began to rain

Comment: When as children, mothers used to caution their kids not to tell lies, otherwise the 雷, ("lei") would 霹 ("pi") you. 霹 means to break something violently, and so to the ancients this is more the work of a bolt of lightning, (which is visible), rather than a thunderous but unseen sound from a 雷.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to 汉典:

[霹雳](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%9C%B9%E9%9B%B3) (pīlì) mainly means **thunderbolt** as the atmospherical phenomenon.

> 又急又响的雷，是云与地面之间发生的强烈雷电现象
>
> sudden and loud thunder, it's the strong lightning bolt occurring between the clouds and earth

[雷霆](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%9B%B7%E9%9C%86) (léitíng) mainly means **thunderclap**, as the booming sound of the thunderbolt, and it's also used figuratively. In English that would be **thunderous**.

> 洪大而急发的雷声
>
> booming and sudden thunder clap

> 比喻声威或怒气
>
> describes metaphorically prestige or rage (thunderous, roaring)

---

In your examples, the two words look similar because of context:

> 空中雷霆一响

Here it's definitely thunderclap, reinforced by the presence of 响, denoting a sound. (The usage of “一 yī” follows the ["一 (yī) ～ 就 (jiù)" structure](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/%e4%b8%80-%e5%b0%b1-vs-%e4%ba%86-%e5%b0%b1), events in quick sequence). "A thunderclap from the sky, ...".

Translating as "The thunderbolt" is not *wrong*, but that seems poetic license on the translator's part, which is fine, since the sentence can't be nicely translated word-for-word.

> 我听到了一声霹雳

Here 霹雳 is preceded by 一声, which works as a classifier / measure word, and results in "one sound of thunderbolt". Therefore "I heard a clap of thunder."

Comment: "空中雷霆一响，就把孩子吓哭了". 响 in 一响 here is not a measure word. 一响 here set up a sequence. It's more like "once", "when", "after", etc. The sentence roughly means "Hearing the thunder, the boy was frightened to cry."

Comment: Compare to: 铃声一响，同学们马上就进教室了。

Comment: @dan Your analysis is correct, as a matter of fact I did not say that 一响 is a measure word...

Comment: ok, this part makes me think you might take it as a measure word "Here it's definitely thunderclap, reinforced by 一响. "A thunderclap from the sky""

Comment: @dan thanks for bringing that up, edited for clarity

Answer (score 2):

> As a noun, both 霹靂 and 雷霆 can be translated as "thunderbolt"

To find the difference between them, we can look into the idioms associate with the two terms:

- 雷霆萬均(之勢) = Thunderous (momentum)
- 大發雷霆 =  Raging furiously; thunderous rage
- 晴天霹靂 = Thunder from a clear sunny sky

From the idioms above, it seems like:

- 霹靂 is mainly used as a noun for 'thunderbolt' or 'sound of a  thunderclap'
- 雷霆 is mainly used in a metaphorical sense. As an adjective for "thunderous" e.g. 雷霆一擊 (a thunderous strike)

Answer (score 0):

> 我听到了一声霹雳，随后天空突然开始下起了雨

To me, this sentence is a bit off, because 霹雳 is usually a vision of lightening.  I will probably put: 一道霹雳，随后天空突然开始下起了雨。 or 就见一道霹雳，随后天空突然开始下起了雨。

> 空中雷霆一响，就把孩子吓哭了。

This sentence makes a lot of sense.

So, the difference: **雷霆 is more of sounding and 霹雳 is more of vision.**